# Tangent lines to the graph of $f(x)=3x(5x^2+1)$ that are parallel to the line $y=8x+9$

Tags: calculus

Determine the equations of the tangent lines to the graph of $f(x)=3x(5x^2+1)$
that are parallel to the line $y=8x+9.$

I really don't know how to do this question; please help me out.

Comment: The slope of the line $y=8x+9$ is $8$.  So find all $x$-values at which the derivative is $8$.  For each of those $x$ values, there is a corresponding value of $y=f(x)$, so you have a point the line passes through and you have a slope. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=3x(5x^2 +1)$

We can find the slope of the tangent line to this curve by differentiating it.

If we denote the derivative of $f(x)$ as $f'(x)$, we find that

$f(x)=3x(5x^2 +1)= 15x^3 + 3x$

By the Power Rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule, we have that:

$f'(x)=45x^2+3$

The line you were given, $y=8x+9$ has a slope of 8. ($y=mx+b$, where m is the slope)

So you want to find out the *x* value for which $f'(x)$, the slope of the tangent line to the curve, equals 8.

So, just set the equal to another.

$8=45x^2+3$

Just solve that for *x* and you have the *x*-values at which the slopes of the tangent lines to the curve equal the slope of the given line.

For two lines to be parallel, of course they have to have the same slope; that is all you need to find. For curves, the "slope" is just the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the line $y=8x+9$ is $8$.  So find all $x$-values at which the derivative is $8$.  For each of those $x$ values, there is a corresponding value of $y=f(x)$, so you have a point the line passes through and you have a slope.

If this is the kind of question that challenges you, then your preparation for calculus is very weak.  Not surprising since universities encourage vast droves of unprepared students to take calculus.  They bring money, after all.